# Any way to enable or add the breadcrumbs to SharePoint sites (office 365) in modern experience without using custom SPFx and custom script editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft

I'm trying to add a breadcrumb in SharePoint Online (Office 365). Is there any way to enable or add the breadcrumbs  in modern experience without using custom SPFx and custom script editor? I'm using a [WSP solution](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/02/12/create-a-modern-breadcrumb-navigation-on-sharepoint/) for the breadcrumb but it only works in classic experience.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Modern UI you will get the breadcrumb out of the box. Below is an example from a document library where the user is currently in folder 3 and from the breadcrumb can see where that folder is located AND navigate to anywhere in breadcrumn by clicking on it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need a breadcrumb for site pages Like Home>Site>Subsite ...

Comment: Np :) If you use modern UI sites you will have the benefit of hub sites, that shares a very nice navigation between them. Its very easy to create a hub and asscociate new sites to it. Both manually or programmatically during a custom site provisioning. 

If you are using classic sites, you will be able to use the top navigation, it wont show a bread crumb, but it will show all sites including Home and highlight which sub site you are currently visiting.